# Is there any way I can change My Cucumber tags on gitlab ci/cd format

Tags: java, junit, gitlab, continuous-integration, cucumber

package runner;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

```
    plugin = {
            "html:target/cucumber-report.html",
            "rerun:target/rerun.txt" ,
            "timeline:target/cucumber",
    },
    features = "src/test/resources/feature",
    glue = "steps",
    dryRun = false,
    tags = "@wi"
```

)
public class  CukesRunner {

}
I want to change tags dynamically I tried almost everything doesn't work I use gradle

I tried to following ways :
./gradlew test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@yourTag" many other ways still can't find a way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.